# what kinds of questions should I ask my manger before I start the internship?

Tags: internship

I just invited my manager for a coffee before I start the internship at Weber Shandwick(PR company). The position is in new business and marketing team of corporate communication department.

My previous experience is all about media. I am not sure what I can do and the prospects for growth in the new company. I am interested in PR industry so I really want to get a full-time job after internship. What kinds of questions should I ask my manger? Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]. Could you make an [edit] to your post to clarify what your problem is? Is there a specific reason you don't think you can ask about what you want to know about the company? Are you looking for suggestions on how to approach asking a specific tough question you are worried may be a sensitive issue? You will get a lot better answers if you add a bit of detail on what you are specifically looking for rather than general advice on what to ask. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should, first and foremost, tackle logistics. This will make your first day go much more smoothly - a pleasant experience for everyone involved. Some examples:

- When should you show up the first day?
- Where are you going on the first day? (e.g. the reception desk)
- Where should you park, if you are driving there?
- What should you bring with you, if anything besides the clothes on your back?

After that, make a list of things you want to know, and ask about them. Do keep in mind that your personal relationship with your manager is non-existent or only just beginning, so you should keep it professional (e.g. don't ask if there are any jerks for which you should watch out.) You do not know how your manager will react yet, since you are not personally familiar with your manager.

Most of the questions I can see you having, such as questions about full-time positions and advancement opportunities, may be things you should have asked during the interview process to see if the company was a good fit for your career goals. Still, you could bring these topics up; just be careful not to come off as assuming you will be offered a full-time position after your internship.

If you can conceive of any reason why a question would be perceived as unprofessional or off-putting, save it for later. Better safe than sorry!